# Allow null value when parsing file to datatable

Tags: c#, parsing, datatable

Parsing a file into a datable how do I allow it to add a null value if for say their is no value for that row in the csv file?

```
string fileName = @".csv";

using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(fileName))
{

    DataTable dt = CsvParser.Parse(stream);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        try
        {
            string lname = Convert.ToString(row[0].ToString().Trim());
            string fname = Convert.ToString(row[1].ToString().Trim());
            long s = Convert.ToInt64(row[2]);
            string b = Convert.ToString(row[3]);
            rec = row[0].ToString() + "," +
                    row[1].ToString() + "," +
                    row[2].ToString() + "," +
                    row[3].ToString() + ",";
            write.WriteLine(rec);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you describe what `CsvParser` is?

Comment: If there is no value for a row in the CSV file then there is no row in the DB.  Did you mean "If there was no value for the cell/column?"

Comment: yes if their is no value in the cell for that column.

Comment: rec = ((row[0]==DBNull.Value)?"":row[0].ToString()) + "," + ... should do the trick. Combined to a linq expression it would be even better

Comment: there is more to my code; Uses the values parsed to the datatable to look up if theres a match in a sql table. I write what is in the file to a new file as well as write what I found in the sql datatabase to a new file as well to see difference in data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your representation of `null` is in the file.  Based on what you're showing, it would seem that whitepsace strings are `null` (you're calling `Trim` on each one), so you could just check for that and do the following:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    // Get values.
    string lname = row[0].Field<string>().Trim();
    string fname = row[1].Field<string>().Trim();
    string sString = row[2].Field<string>().Trim();
    string b = row[3].Field<string>().Trim();

    // Format/parse.
    lname = lname == "" ? null : lname;
    fname = fname == "" ? null : fname;
    long? s = sString == "" ? (long?) null : Convert.ToInt64(sString);
    string b = b == "" ? null : b;

    // Process the values.
}
```

Note, depending on what the implementation of `CsvParser` is, you might be getting back [`DbNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/934efkk6.aspx) instead of actual blank strings.  Note that the call to `Field` will handle that conversion to `null` if you use it (but then you have to be careful to not call `Trim` on it if it's `null`, otherwise, a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown).

Comment: get the error no overload method for Field argument.. I only need to allow null/blank values for s and b values

Comment: @LewSim You need the [`DataRowExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) class to use the `Field` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

This works and accpet null value.

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                                string lname = row[0].ToString();
                                string fname = row[1].ToString();

                                string ss1 = row[2].ToString();
                                long? s = ss1 == "" ? (long?)null : Convert.ToInt64(ssn1);

                                string dob1 = row[3].ToString();
                                string b = dob1 == "" ? null : dob1;
```